# Webrtc audio does not always work bidirectionally

Tags: google-chrome, audio, webrtc

I am using simple-Webrtc in my local network (so please forget about ice/stun/or turn).
I use google Chrome to connect two peers into a room. But I have problem with the Audio on some machines. The problem is I can only hear in one direction. However, when I try different machine, I can hear the audio bidirectionally. Do you know what is the reason and how I can fix it?
I am using the same version(Version 29.0.1547.76 m) of Google chrome on all machines.